# timer tick event, won't be interrupted by other functions?

Tags: c#, events, timer

So here is a game from a book i've been studying.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add((Keys)random.Next(65, 90));

    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 7)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Game over");
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(e.KeyCode);
        listBox1.Refresh();
        if (timer1.Interval > 400)
            timer1.Interval -= 10;
        if (timer1.Interval > 250)
            timer1.Interval -= 7;
        if (timer1.Interval > 100)
            timer1.Interval -= 2;
        difficultyProgressBar.Value = 800 - timer1.Interval;
        stats.Update(true);
    }

    else
    {
        stats.Update(false);
    }
    correctLabel.Text = "Correct: " + stats.Correct;
    missedLabel.Text = "Missed: " + stats.Missed;
    totalLabel.Text = "Total: " + stats.Total;
    accuracyLabel.Text = "Accuracy: " + stats.Accuracy + "%";
}
```

It generates random letters, and if you press the right letter, it has to remove the letter pressed, from the listbox.

Problem is that Form's keydown property won't work, it only highlights the key pressed, but it won't remove it from the listbox, the cycle continues untill the listbox is full, and it gives game over message then...

I wonder what did i do wrong this time, since the whole code is taken from the book itself?

Comment: Did you add the method as the event handler for the appropriate event on the form?  Also, I'd think it ought to be previewKeyDown instead, assuming something other than the form has focus.

Comment: Yes i did add the method, just tried previewKeyDown, it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried an isolated troubleshoot? I mean use the `Form1_KeyDown` event and just use `MessageBox.Show("HERE");` or something similar to make sure the event is firing?

Comment: I just tried, nothing happens.

Comment: Interestingly i have downloaded the code from their site, it is exactly  the same code but mine doesn't work, and the one i downloaded works, i am clueless again.

Comment: As @Servy said, you are probably missing the explicit wiring up of the event handler - simply copying in the code is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked both my code and the books', the problem was their Forms KeyPreview was set to True, and mine wasn't, so that was the answer which they forgot to mention on the book unfortunately.